# Java Jersey How to Upload File with the File as Parameter

Tags: java, rest, file, jersey

I have a method in the resource class, uploadFile. It calls a method that takes in a file as a parameter and then split the files into parts before writing said parts to disk.

I would like to know how to write a client test for it, assuming it's possible to upload a file without using @FormDataParam InputStream. Because I don't think I need it in this case.

I've seen plenty of examples for uploading files with Jersey that takes in InputStream and FormDataContentDisposition as @FormDataParam but I'm not sure if that's mandatory.

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadfile/{file}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@PathParam("file") File file, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws IOException {
    FileSplit.splitFile(file); //Write file to disk
    String output = "File successfully uploaded";  
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}

//Method to write file to disk
public static void splitFile(File f) throws IOException {
    int partCounter = 1;

    int sizeOfFiles = (int) (f.length() / 3);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

    String fileName = f.getName();

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {

        int bytesAmount = 0;
        while ((bytesAmount = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            String filePartName = String.format("%s.%03d", fileName, partCounter++);
            File newFile = new File("D:\\", filePartName);
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesAmount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u use Socket to sending requests like `HttpUrlConnection` u can write file bytes in `outPutStream` and in server side use `HttpServletRequest` and process `request.getInputStream()` to write bytes in your storage.

or if u can use `multipart-formdata` to sending requests and catch file with `RequestPart() MultiPartFile file` to uploading file.

i hope this will be helpful